# Flutter Exception : ( Stream Builder Show issue ... null check operator used on a null value !! )

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

m trying to show The  users That have connection with the current user in The Stream Builder of The Home page and i am facing this issue !!

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: controller.chatsStream(),
    builder: (context, snapshot1) {
      if(snapshot1.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      else if (snapshot1.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        var listDocsChats = snapshot1.data!.docs;
        print("List of Connections");
        print(listDocsChats);
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemCount: listDocsChats.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return StreamBuilder<
                DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
              stream: controller
                  .friendStream(listDocsChats[index]["connection"]),
              builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                if(snapshot2.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                else {
                  var data = snapshot2.data!.data();
                  return data!["status"] == ""
                      ? ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 5,
                    ),
                    onTap: (){},
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        child: data["photoUrl"] == ""
                            ? Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/219983.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                            : Image.network(
                          "${data["photoUrl"]}",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "${data["name"]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: listDocsChats[index]
                    ["total_unread"] ==
                        0
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
                      label: Text(
                        "${listDocsChats[index]["total_unread"]}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                      : ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 5,
                    ),
                    onTap: (){},
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        child: data["photoUrl"] == ""
                            ? Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/219983.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                            : Image.network(
                          "${data["photoUrl"]}",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "${data["name"]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${data["status"]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: listDocsChats[index]
                    ["total_unread"] ==
                        0
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
                      label: Text(
                        "${listDocsChats[index]["total_unread"]}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
        );
      }else{
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  );
```

And This is The Home Controller :

```
class HomeController extends GetxController{
        final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

          chatsStream(){
             return 
               FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").
               doc(auth!.email).collection("chats")
               .orderBy("lastTime" , descending: true).snapshots();
   }

            friendStream(String email){
           FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(email).snapshots();
     }
    }
```

And This Is My Firebase Database !

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR40G.png)

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXVlP.png)

And This Is The Exception !!

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library 
    =======================================================
   The following _CastError was thrown building 
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, state: 
    _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, 
  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#3685c):
 Null check operator used on a null value

 The relevant error-causing widget was: 
   StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> 

  StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/flutter/chat_app_newversion/lib
 /app/modules/home/view/contents/home_view_body.dart:30:24
   When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
 #0      HomeBody.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
(package:chat_app_newversion/app/modules/home/view/contents/home_view_body.dart:41:48)
 #1      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:442:81)
 #2      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
 #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
 #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
 #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
  (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
 #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
 #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild 
   (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
 #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
     (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
 #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
       ...     Normal element mounting (33 frames)
```

i Want To show The Users or The friends that The current User had a connection with (
The connection between the users Create when one of the users search for the other ...
)

Comment: Please don't use images to represent database data or code. Put the information in as text instead.

Comment: How can i show you The Firebase Data base with Text :)

Comment: I’m recommending putting this in as text using tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR40G.png

Comment: Next Time i will ... Thank you , i find The Solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: controller.chatsStream(),
    builder: (context, snapshot1) {
      if(snapshot1.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      else if (snapshot1.hasData && snapshot1.data != null) {
        var listDocsChats = snapshot1.data!.docs;
        print("List of Connections");
        print(listDocsChats);
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemCount: listDocsChats.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return StreamBuilder<
                DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
              stream: controller
                  .friendStream(listDocsChats[index]["connection"]),
              builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                if(snapshot2.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                else if(snapshot2.hasData && snapshot2.data != null) {
                  var data = snapshot2.data!.data();
                  return data!["status"] == ""
                      ? ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 5,
                    ),
                    onTap: (){},
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        child: data["photoUrl"] == ""
                            ? Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/219983.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                            : Image.network(
                          "${data["photoUrl"]}",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "${data["name"]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: listDocsChats[index]
                    ["total_unread"] ==
                        0
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
                      label: Text(
                        "${listDocsChats[index]["total_unread"]}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                      : ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 5,
                    ),
                    onTap: (){},
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        child: data["photoUrl"] == ""
                            ? Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/219983.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                            : Image.network(
                          "${data["photoUrl"]}",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "${data["name"]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${data["status"]}",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: listDocsChats[index]
                    ["total_unread"] ==
                        0
                        ? const SizedBox()
                        : Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
                      label: Text(
                        "${listDocsChats[index]["total_unread"]}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }else {
                  return const SizedBox();
                }
              },
            );
          } ,
        );
      }else{
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  );
```